# SCNView exported Collada (.dae) file looks different and impossible to import to Blender

Tags: xcode, scenekit

I have a problem with exporting scene from `SCNView`.
In Xcode I made simple scene with light and one big, transparent box. 
Colourful small boxes are generated inside running application.
Scene in SCNView looks like this:
 [image]

I'm happy with this.
But if I export file by

```
@IBAction func exportDAE(_ sender: Any) {
    if let scene = view3D.scene {
        let panel = NSSavePanel()
        panel.allowedFileTypes = ["dae"]
        panel.runModal()
        if let url = panel.url {
            scene.write(to: url,
                        options: nil,
                        delegate: nil,
                        progressHandler: nil);
        }
    }
}
```

An error is thrown:

```
2019-12-02 13:27:16.450749+0100 ShowMeInstances[83949:14810790] errors encountered while discovering extensions: Error Domain=PlugInKit Code=13 "query cancelled" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=query cancelled}
```

all small boxes are destroyed, only one big looks OK:

[image]

Sometimes materials are broken too: (those magenta destroyed boxes should have similar color to surrounded boxes:

[image]
In AppDelegate I defined:

```
var instancesNode: InstancesNode? = nil
```

which is inited by:

```
class InstancesNode: SCNNode {
    typealias CoordUnit = Double

    var instanceGenerator: InstanceGenerator<CoordUnit>?
    init(with data: Data) throws {

            self.instanceGenerator = try InstanceGenerator(from: data)

        super.init()

        for instance in instanceGenerator?.instances ?? [] {
            let coords = instance.coordinates.map( {$0.value})
            let color =  getMaterialDiffuseColor(for: coords)
            let coords3D = convertCoordinatesTo3D(coords)
            let node = Instance3D(
                name: instance.instanceName,
                coordinates: coords3D,
                color: color)

            self.addChildNode(node)
        }
    }
.....
}
```

now `Instance3D` is inited by

```
class Instance3D: SCNNode {

    init (name: String, coordinates: SCNVector3, color: NSColor) {
        super.init()
        self.name = name

        let box = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)
        let material = SCNMaterial()
        material.diffuse.contents = color
        material.emission.contents = color
        material.lightingModel = .lambert
        material.metalness.contents = 0
        material.shininess = 1

        box.materials = [material]

        self.position = coordinates
        self.geometry = box
    }
```

Everything is inserted into scene by

```
view3D.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(instancesNode!)
```

in appDelegate. Without this line only big box and light are visible in view.

Also file cannot be imported by Blender, Blender silently and immediately explodes.

What could be a reason? Is it a feature or is it a bug?

Comment: can you share the code that generates the big and small cubes?

Comment: Big cube is added via editor. Give me few minutes.

Comment: I added code and tried to explain logic how this structure is created.

Answer (score 0):

When I generate just one Instance, generated box is OK, can import file to Blender, if two — only one is OK, Blender explodes. If i change box to sphere — one one sphere is visible in QuickLook

Definitely bug.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm. The following code, once exported from SceneKit in .dae format will crash Blender (and will cause an error in Meshlab, and not render correctly in Mac OS X's finder preview).

```
var radius = 0.0005
let s1 = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(radius)))
let s2 = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: CGFloat(radius)))
s1.position = SCNVector3(0,0,0)
s2.position = SCNVector3(1,0,0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(s1)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(s2)
```